# How is it possible that my app reaches the daily 10,000 query quota on the google youtube api?

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api

So in my google developer console it says that I reached the 10,000 queries quota after a few hours of coding my app, how is this possible? My app is a youtube clone which uses only 3 calls each time it is run, for the 3 home/trending/subscription feeds, and another call which is used when you search for something.

I'm going to give you my cellForItemAt part that calls these functions. If you want to see all the functions I can give you the git link since my app is split into data layer/domain layer/ ui layer which makes it quite a long path to the JSONdecoder function which is a simple completion handler that returns an array of videos. Also I know the functions get called every time I slide the collection view but i really don't slide it that much while using it, and previously I used to call the fetch functions in viewdidload and I still reached the daily quota, although after 3 hours.

I have already tried using only one call while making the app and I still managed to reach the quota pretty fast. I do test the app a lot, but i doubt that I run it over 30 or 40 times per hour...

EDIT: Haha I figured it out, collectionView.reloadData() kept calling the functions over and over again, i just got a new api key and let it run for literally 30 seconds and api calls are up to 4000. Haha, I'm laughing so much now, thanks for the replies!

```
        if indexPath.row == 3{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: accountCellId, for: indexPath)
            guard let accountCell = cell as? AccountCell else {return cell}
            return accountCell
        }

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        guard let feedCell = cell as? SlidingVideoFeedCell else {return cell}
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            fetchHome()
            feedCell.setUpViews(videos: videoFeeds["home"], images: images)
        case 1:
            fetchTrending()
            feedCell.setUpViews(videos: videoFeeds["trending"], images: images)
        case 2:
            fetchSubscription()
            feedCell.setUpViews(videos: videoFeeds["subscription"], images: images)
        default:
            print("out of range")
        }
            return feedCell
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you add a log each time you make a call to the API so you can see how often you are actually calling it.

Comment: If you're making an API call whenever a cell is loaded, you're doing a LOT more calls than you expect. Instead you should do those calls outside any display logic and update your collection view once you have the data.

Comment: counter logs 17 calls with 3 cells. It's probably 5 or 6 times that actually, since I just reached my quota again.Actually those cells are more like views that contain cells within them, the call gets an array of videos and then lists them inside the 'cell', which covers the enitre screen. It's based on the old iOS youtube app, where you have the sliding menu on top. This is actually my dataSource class, it's connected to the ViewController which has the collection view in itself. One thing I can think of making tons of calls is .reloadData() being called every time a video feed is fetched...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will reach the quota anyway, I suggest trying youtube innertube API. It is used internally by google, so it doesn't have quotas, but it is also bot documented.
Another way of doing it would be scraping the pages with the videos.